# Android viewport issues after upgrading Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, viewport

My cordova application is built with a fixed width of 640px.
I'm having trouble having it appear uniformly on both iOS and Android
It works fine for iOS with the following viewport settings:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5" />`

It also works fine for older android phones with the above viewport, but on the galaxy s4, the layout and all of the elements on the screen are extra large.

I can get the layout looking more or less correct for the galaxy s4 with these viewport settings:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1.65, maximum-scale=1.65, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">`

however, then it breaks on all other devices.  Obviously this is not a solution.

I have tried adjusting the `target-densityDpi` with many other combinations of settings, but it never exactly fixes the issue.

Before upgrading to cordova 4.0.0, this was not an issue and the s4 was displaying properly with this viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5" />`

Has anyone else experienced issues like this?